# How do I trick Xorg into seeing a TCP remote control as user activity?

Tags: debian, x11, kodi

I have a new home-made HTPC running Debian bullseye + X11 + LightDM + Kodi 19. The HTPC is connected to a Plasma screen and my local network but not much else (no mouse, no keyboard). Kodi is controlled through Kore, an android remote control app for Kodi that works over the network.

My problem is that X doesn't see the remote control's actions as user activity so, after about 10mn, the screen goes black and a mouse has to be plugged-in and jiggled to wake up the screen.

My first idea was to disable DPMS and be done with it:

```
nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf
```

```
Section "Extensions"
        Option      "DPMS" "Disable"
EndSection
```

But for some reason it didn't work. In the meantime, I changed my mind and thought that having the screen go black after real inactivity would be great, considering the screen is a Plasma and is prone to burn-ins.

So: Ho do I make X11 see Kore's inputs as user activity?

I have an idea, which would be to make Kore connect to a dummy port (say 8081). Then have a python script running forever on the HTPC, listening on 8081 and forwarding requests to the port Kodi listens on (say 8082). Every time my script proxies a requests, it would trigger a key press (something like Ctrl pressed + Ctrl released to avoid side-effect). I haven't tested it yet but I thought I'd get some different ideas form the community first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lightdm` is using its own `light-locker` screensaver/locker implementation, perhaps you could arrange each remote controller action to also run `light-locker-command --poke`? The [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/light-locker/light-locker-command.1.en.html) describes that as "Poke the running locker to simulate user activity".

But if you are using bare Xorg DPMS, then that option is not available.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can't +1 for now, as I don't have the "reputation" but I'll come back to it when I do. Anyway, I think your answer pointed me in the right direction. I'll post a full answer when I find the time to test the solution (unless someone else has a better idea).

Comment: As a writer of the question, you can always mark an answer as "accepted" (the green checkmark) - it's equivalent of +1.5 votes. But wait a few days first, to see if someone writes a better answer. Welcome to SE.

Answer (score 0):

1. What window manager (gnome, kde, xfce, lxde, etc) are you using?   Whichever it is, check its Screensaver settings, there should be a way to disable it entirely.  There definitely is for xfce4 (which is what I'm using), but I don't know about the others.  If your window-manager doesn't support disabling the screensaver, then consider switching to one that does.

   Depending on your WM, you may also have to use the Power Management settings to disable "Display power management" (or whatever name your WM calls DPMS).
2. Hardware hack: get an old keyboard, pry off the key-cap for the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or <kbd>Control</kbd> key and plug it in to a USB port.   Devise and build a circuit to trigger a keypress every 9 minutes or so (or increase the screensaver delay to as high as it will go and trigger it every XX hours - as infrequently as possible while still often enough to prevent the screensaver from starting).

   You may be able to find help on the circuit design on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or some other electronics site.

   BTW, the reason for using Shift, Alt, or Ctrl is that they are modifier keys only - they won't insert a character into your terminal or whatever document you might be editing....and a momentary trigger once every XX minutes is fairly unlikely to have any noticeable effect.  <kbd>Shift</kbd> is probably the best choice - probably the worst it can do is (very rarely) capitalise a letter you happen to be typing at the exact moment it's triggering.

   A variation of this is to use an old mouse instead of a keyboard, with some device to trigger a scroll-wheel event or tiny mouse movement event every XX minutes.   Again, like modifier keys, a scroll-wheel or movement event is less likely to cause annoyance than a mouse-click.
3. Similar to the hardware hack: it might be worthwhile searching for existing USB devices that can do something similar, maybe some kind of programmable USB HID device.  Dunno if such a thing actually exists.  Maybe a little ARM SBC like a Raspberry Pi, or an old Android phone running [USB Gadget Tool](https://github.com/tejado/android-usb-gadget) or similar.

Comment: Thank you but I feel like these are answers to a different question. As I explained in the second part, it's not about preventing the screen to go blank all the time. This is a plasma TV. If I fall asleep in front of it, it better go blank after 10mn (risk of burn-in). What I'd like is to have my network remote be counted as user input by X11 so that it delays the screensaver/screen-blanking while I'm navigating through the menus. (PS: I'm not using a WM, just X11, lightDM and Kodi)